# How to generate multiple rows from each single row of a dataframe with a function(s) and then join/merge them back in?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mapply

I start with a dataframe where each row has a long string that represents a 2D environment (let's call it a landscape) in 1D. In the real case these are approximately 6 values tall and 80 values long, and thus in 1D the strings are 480 characters long. I've shortened these in the example. Each row also has a unique name that's a shorthand identifier for each landscape.

I have a function that takes each row, cuts the string up into 6 strips, and does analysis on each. In this example, the core action of the function is compressing the strips and getting the compression length. This function results in a 6-row dataframe, which I need to combine with the original dataframe, with the result being a final dataframe that has 6 rows for every 1 row of the original.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

master_df <- tribble(~land_id, ~land_string,
                     "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab",
                     "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb")

compress_it <- function(txt) {
  len.raw <- sum(nchar(txt))
  len.gz <- length(memCompress(txt, "g"))
  return(list("len_raw" = len.raw,
              "len_gz" = len.gz))
}

get_strip_data <- function(land_id, land_string) {
    with_spaces <- gsub("(.{5})", "\\1 ", land_string)
    chars_on_lines <- str_replace_all(with_spaces, pattern = " ", "\n")
    prob_matrix <- read.table(text = chars_on_lines, header=FALSE, sep = " ",
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    prob_matrix <- mutate(prob_matrix, 
                          land_id = land_id,
                          substr_id = 1:nrow(prob_matrix) )
    prob_matrix <- rename(prob_matrix, land_substring = V1)

    mutate(prob_matrix, new = map(land_substring, compress_it)) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(new))
}

get_strip_data(master_df$land_id[[2]], master_df$land_string[[2]]) # to test the above function
```

Here's where we get into pseudocode/klugecode for what I'm trying to do.

First, I make an empty dataframe.

```
subchunks_df <- 
  tribble(~land_id, ~land_string, ~land_substring, ~substr_id, ~len_raw, ~len_gz,
          "", "", "", NA, NA, NA)
```

Attempt a for loop:

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(master_df) ) {
  subchunks_df[i, ] <- get_strip_data(master_df$land_id[[i]], master_df$land_string[[i]])
}
```

Attempt a mapply instead:

```
subchunks_df <- mapply(get_strip_data, 
                       land_id = master_df$land_id, 
                       land_string = master_df$land_string)
```

Nope. My attempts are, to be generous, "close but no cigar."

If I can get subchunks_df in the right shape, I would then right_join:

```
final_df <- right_join(master_df, subchunks_df, by = "land_id")
```

This is the desired output given the master_df going through the functions:

```
final_df <- 
  tribble(~land_id, ~land_string, ~land_substring, ~substr_id, ~len_raw, ~len_gz, 
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "aaaaa", 1, 5, 11,     
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "aaaaa", 2, 5, 11,     
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "baaaa", 3, 5, 11,     
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "abaaa", 4, 5, 13,     
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "babab", 5, 5, 13,     
          "v1-few_bs", "aaaaaaaaaabaaaaabaaabababaabab", "aabab", 6, 5, 13,
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "aaaaa", 1, 5, 11,        
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "aaaaa", 2, 5, 11,        
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "babba", 3, 5, 13,        
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "bbbab", 4, 5, 13,        
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "babab", 5, 5, 13,        
          "v2-more_bs", "aaaaaaaaaababbabbbabbababaabbb", "aabbb", 6, 5, 13)
```

As always, I would appreciate both a dplyr and base R perspective on this. I'm not convinced my function for taking in the strips and getting the compression length is all that great either. I couldn't find anything simpler. But this last mile has been the real trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map functional are the tidyverse version of the apply family. The map_dfr function is using the vector master_df$land_id index. Think about it like a for loop. It gives you the data frame you're looking for the right_join call.

```
library(tidyverse)
subchunks_df <- map_dfr(seq_along(master_df$land_id), function(i){
                     get_strip_data(master_df$land_id[[i]], 
                                    master_df$land_string[[i]])})

final_df <- right_join(master_df, subchunks_df, by = "land_id")
```

Comment: I couldn't get a for loop working correctly either, which is why I finally posted. I caught a glimpse of your first example using `subchunks_df <-i map_dfr(master_df$land_id, ~ get_strip_data(master_df$land_id[[.y]], master_df$land_string[[.y]]) )` which does work, but seems slower than your final edited example. Hopefully someone will provide a base R example too, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around both `map` and `apply`. And understanding the syntax for `for` loops, `map`, and `apply` families for R seems essential for me (and others) to become ok at R!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Map` and then bind the data together with `do.call` + `rbind`

```
subchunks_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(get_strip_data, master_df$land_id, 
                                    master_df$land_string))
```

Or if you prefer `tidyverse`, you can use `map2_df`

```
subchunks_df <- purrr::map2_df(master_df$land_id, master_df$land_string, 
                               get_strip_data)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   land_substring land_id    substr_id len_raw len_gz
#   <chr>          <chr>          <int>   <int>  <int>
# 1 aaaaa          v1-few_bs          1       5     11
# 2 aaaaa          v1-few_bs          2       5     11
# 3 baaaa          v1-few_bs          3       5     11
# 4 abaaa          v1-few_bs          4       5     13
# 5 babab          v1-few_bs          5       5     13
# 6 aabab          v1-few_bs          6       5     13
# 7 aaaaa          v2-more_bs         1       5     11
# 8 aaaaa          v2-more_bs         2       5     11
# 9 babba          v2-more_bs         3       5     13
#10 bbbab          v2-more_bs         4       5     13
#11 babab          v2-more_bs         5       5     13
#12 aabbb          v2-more_bs         6       5     13
```

and then `right_join` :

```
final_df <- dplyr::right_join(master_df, subchunks_df, by = "land_id")
```

Comment: In your first example, isn't `map` also in `purrr`, and thus it IS a `tidyverse` example? `map` certainly doesn't seem to be in base R.

Comment: @StanRhodes `map` is different than `Map`. `map` is in `purrr` whereas `Map` is base R. R is case sensitive.

Comment: Mea culpa, my apologies. That function is hard to find in the R documentation. I found some in `funprog {base}`: "`Map` is a simple wrapper to `mapply` which does not attempt to simplify the result, similar to Common Lisp's `mapcar` (with arguments being recycled, however)."